# How to deal with multibyte search in solr?

Tags: solr, multibyte

How to tell solr to search or deal with multibyte numbers like `٦٩` , its just the number `69`

in other words the user has input `٦٩`  into the search box , the browser would convert it to :`%D9%A6%D9%A9`

solr return no result since it doesn't have the value :`%D9%A6%D9%A9`

how to deal with such of these query ???

solr config is the default config

Comment: you mean in solr query? parsing it before and giving him the translated value? or the fields are filled with data in this type?

Comment: in my case filled had the 69 and the user tries to search ٦٩ , parsing and translating the query would be okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert them from these characters to the number using solr.MappingCharFilterFactory https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories

So basically you can have a file `mapping-ArabicNumbersToASCII.txt` and that contains:

```
"٠" => "0"
"١" => "1"
"٢" => "2"
"٣" => "3"
...
```

Then use the it as the analyzer like so:

```
<analyzer>
  <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" 
    mapping="mapping-ArabicNumbersToASCII.txt"/>
  <tokenizer ...>
  [...]
</analyzer>
```